# Подскажите, как сделать, что бы каррированая функция add(a)(b) проходила такой тест add(a,b) === add(a)(b) === a+b

Tags: javascript, jest

Подскажите, как сделать, что бы каррированая функция add(a)(b) проходила такой тест add(a,b) === add(a)(b) === a+b

Код ниже не работает для вызова  add(a,b). Возвращает undefined

```
function add(a) {
    return (b) => {
        return a + b
    }
}
```

Comment: @Grundy, там неограниченное число дубликатов, а тут только 2. Так что не дубликат.

Comment: @Qwertiy, подход-то один и тот же - дубликат

Comment: @Grundy, там надо с рекурсией химичить, а тут в строчку пишется. И ещё тот вариант работает только с `==`, а тут в условии `===`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, тогда добавь там ответ

Comment: @Grundy, так туда этот ответ не подходит. Как и те ответы сюда не подходят (в том числе тот, который не подходит к обоим вопросам).

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код не может работать для вызова `add(a, b)` - он игнорирует второй аргумент. Если это поправить будет что-то вроде:

```
const add = (a, b) => {
    if (b === undefined) {
        return c => a + c;
    }
    return add(a)(b);
};

console.log(add(1, 2));
console.log(add(1)(2));
```

> ```
> $ node temp.js
> 3
> 3
> ```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function add(x, y) {
  return y == null ? y => x + y : x + y
}

console.log(add(1, 2), add(1, 2) === 3)
console.log(add(1)(2), add(1)(2) === 3)
```

Comment: `y == null` -> `y === undefined`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, можно, а зачем?

Comment: Отсутствующий аргумент в JavaScript это именно `undefined`, не `null`. С точки зрения языка вы написали работающую (за счёт правил приведения), но странную конструкцию. В JavaScript приведения - больное место. Всякий нормальный человек держится от них подальше.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, у меня нет причин складывать с null, а значит нет и причин разделять null и undefined.